# What does "on the spot" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "on the spot" mean in football (soccer)?

> Aubameyang places the ball on the spot. He takes a few paces back. He strolls up to the ball, sidefoots it feebly to his right, and having gone the right way Ederson can hardly fail to save it!

Answer (score 1):

It's the [white mark](https://youtu.be/SlV_4UwbOBkused) used to take the penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's referring to the penalty kick marker:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_kick_(association_football)

As part of the procedure for a penalty kick, the ball is placed on a mark on the ground, which can also be referred to as a spot. The player then steps back and kicks the ball towards the goal. In this case, the player kicked the ball right toward where the goalie was moving toward, and it was an easy save for the goalie.